# Can't understand the logic of a JavaScript code block [Bulls and Cows game]

Tags: javascript

I'm in need of a little help. I need to write a detailed interpretation of a JavaScript code for a game of Bulls and Cows and I don't understand exactly what's happening in the main logic block. This is the block:

```
        //Check Bull,Cow,Try Again
    var bull, cow;

    if (check) {
        bull = 0;
        cow = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < getNum.length; i++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < userText.length; k++) {
                if ((getNum[i] == userText[k]) && (i == k)) {
                    bull++;
                } else if ((getNum[i] == userText[k]) && (i != k)) {
                    cow++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (bull == 0 && cow == 0) {
            setText.innerHTML += "try again\n";
        } else if (bull == numLength) {
            setText.innerHTML += numLength + " bulls! you won the game!!!\nclick restart to play again\n";
        } else {
            setText.innerHTML += userText + " : ";
            setText.innerHTML += (bull + " bull(s), " + cow + " cow(s)!\n");
        }
    }
    check = true;

}
```

Also here's the entire program in case you need to check the interconnection of variables and such:

```
var getNum = new Array();
var numLength;
var check = true;

window.onload = function() {
    numLength = document.getElementById("select").value;
    setNumber();
}

/*Get random numbers
Numbers must not be the same as each other
(found this entire codeblock on the internet
and adapted it, not gonna lie)*/
function setNumber() {
    var random;
    getNum.splice(0, getNum.length);
    while (getNum.length < numLength) {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < getNum.length; i++) {
            if (getNum[i] == random) {
                check = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (check) {
            getNum.push(random);
        }
        check = true;
    }
}

//Check user number
function checkUserText() {
    var userText = document.getElementById("userText").value;
    var setText = document.getElementById("textArea");
    //Check if userText is number
    for (var i = 0; i < userText.length; i++) {
        if (userText.charCodeAt(i) < 48 || userText.charCodeAt(i) > 57
                || userText.length != numLength) {
            setText.innerHTML += "Type only" + numLength + " numbers!\n";
            check = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    //Check Bull,Cow,Try Again
    var bull, cow;

    if (check) {
        bull = 0;
        cow = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < getNum.length; i++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < userText.length; k++) {
                if ((getNum[i] == userText[k]) && (i == k)) {
                    bull++;
                } else if ((getNum[i] == userText[k]) && (i != k)) {
                    cow++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (bull == 0 && cow == 0) {
            setText.innerHTML += "try again\n";
        } else if (bull == numLength) {
            setText.innerHTML += numLength + " bulls! you won the game!!!\nclick restart to play again\n";
        } else {
            setText.innerHTML += userText + " : ";
            setText.innerHTML += (bull + " bull(s), " + cow + " cow(s)!\n");
        }
    }
    check = true;

}

//change difficulty
function difficulty() {
    numLength = document.getElementById("select").value;
    reload();
}

//restart game
function reload() {
    setNumber();
    document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML = "";
}
```

I understand the general idea of the block but I can't see the specifics, I can't see the logic behind it, if someone could explain this block to me or make a quick flow chart I would be more than grateful.

```js
 var getNum = new Array();
 var numLength;
 var check = true;

 window.onload = function() {
  numLength = document.getElementById("select").value;
  setNumber();
 }

 /*Get random numbers
 Numbers must not be the same as each other
 (found this entire codeblock on the internet
 and adapted it, not gonna lie)*/
 function setNumber() {
  var random;
  getNum.splice(0, getNum.length);
  while (getNum.length < numLength) {
   random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;

   for (var i = 0; i < getNum.length; i++) {
    if (getNum[i] == random) {
     check = false;
     break;
    }
   }

   if (check) {
    getNum.push(random);
   }
   check = true;
  }
 }

 //Check user number
 function checkUserText() {
  var userText = document.getElementById("userText").value;
  var setText = document.getElementById("textArea");
  //Check if userText is number
  for (var i = 0; i < userText.length; i++) {
   if (userText.charCodeAt(i) < 48 || userText.charCodeAt(i) > 57
     || userText.length != numLength) {
    setText.innerHTML += "Type only" + numLength + " numbers!\n";
    check = false;
    break;
   }
  }

  //Check Bull,Cow,Try Again
  var bull, cow;

  if (check) {
   bull = 0;
   cow = 0;

   for (var i = 0; i < getNum.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < userText.length; k++) {
     if ((getNum[i] == userText[k]) && (i == k)) {
      bull++;
     } else if ((getNum[i] == userText[k]) && (i != k)) {
      cow++;
     }
    }
   }

   if (bull == 0 && cow == 0) {
    setText.innerHTML += "try again\n";
   } else if (bull == numLength) {
    setText.innerHTML += numLength + " bulls! you won the game!!!\nclick restart to play again\n";
   } else {
    setText.innerHTML += userText + " : ";
    setText.innerHTML += (bull + " bull(s), " + cow + " cow(s)!\n");
   }
  }
  check = true;

 }
 
 //change difficulty
 function difficulty() {
  numLength = document.getElementById("select").value;
  reload();
 }

 //restart game
 function reload() {
  setNumber();
  document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML = "";
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Bulls and Cows</title>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="operation.js">

     </script>
  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  
  <style>
     h2 {
    font-family: Lobster;
    color: blue;
    }
   body {
    background-color: #cccccc
    }
  </style>
  

 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>Bulls and Cows</h2>
  <label for="userText">Type here: </label>
  <input type="text" id="userText"/>
  <br />
  <button id="ch" onclick="checkUserText()">check</button>
  <button id="re" onclick="reload()">restart</button>
  Length : <select id="select" onchange="difficulty()">
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
   <option>6</option>
   <option>7</option>
   <option>8</option>
   <option>9</option>
   <option>10</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <textarea id="textArea" rows="20" cols="30" readonly="readonly" style="overflow-y: scroll"></textarea>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add a jsfiddle with your code so we can easily see it in action

Comment: So the checkUserText function is likely called on the on.keyup event

Comment: You need a nice clean html example with script using a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: IT is basically validating the number against the number set in the setNumber function when page loads. The number must be a certain length and if you guess the number set on page load you win?

Comment: The function gets called when the event listener is triggered. Or at least that is when it should be!

Comment: Hey guys, I added the fiddle thing at the end of my post, hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, so it's the same as mastermind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// ok lets assume the getNum.length is 3 
// and the random getNum is 123
// and user enters 321 and clicks check


var bull, cow;

if (check) {
    bull = 0;
    cow = 0;



    for (var i = 0; i < getNum.length; i++) {
      // this will loop three times
      // in the first iteration getNum[i] == 1 
      // the second iteration getNum[i] == 2 
      // the third iteration getNum[i] == 3 


        for (var k = 0; k < userText.length; k++) {

          // for each iteration of getNum it will iterate all user input (also 3 times)
          // so 3 times per iteration of getNum, clear so far? good 
          // so at first iteration userText[k] == 3
          // so at second iteration userText[k] == 2
          // so at third iteration userText[k] == 1
          // while i keeps the value of the outer loop

            // this expression checks if user input matches the same number on the same position in getNum
            if ((getNum[i] == userText[k]) && (i == k)) {
                // in the second iteration of the outer loop its a bull because 
                // getNum[i] == 2 == userText[k] == 2 AND 1 == 1 (number and position of number/index is matching the random number
                bull++;
            } else if ((getNum[i] == userText[k]) && (i != k)) {
                // in the first and last iteration of the outer loop its a cow because
                // getNum[i] == 1/2 == userText[k] == 1/2 AND 0/2 is NOT 2/0 (number is matching but position not matching) 
                cow++;
            }

            // if the getNum[i] doesnt exist at all in userText, neither cow or bull will count up
        }
    }

    if (bull == 0 && cow == 0) {
        // so if no number matched - try again
        setText.innerHTML += "try again\n";
    } else if (bull == numLength) {
        // if all numbers and positions (cow) matched you won
        setText.innerHTML += numLength + " bulls! you won the game!!!\nclick restart to play again\n";
    } else {
        // else show how many "cows" and "bulls"
        setText.innerHTML += userText + " : ";
        setText.innerHTML += (bull + " bull(s), " + cow + " cow(s)!\n");
    }

    // so the output of above assumption would be 
    // 1 bull, 2 cows
    // cool game ;-)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed! Have a great day.

Comment: I have another small question you might be able to help me out with, why does this game not work properly with a difficulty higher than 5?

Comment: glad it helped ;-) why do you think its not working properly then? you have any axample?

Comment: only thing i can say is that surely it doesnt work for difficulty higher than 9, because it only works for one-digit-numbers

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fil3cq this is the example, it's impossible for there to be 7 cows in the first one AND the last one